# Perfect Rectangle checker

Tags: java, object-oriented

While submitting this question i found that [someone already made up this question in python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/221875/leetcode-perfect-rectangle), here is my java implementation of the [Perfect-Rectangle-Challange](https://leetcode.com/problems/perfect-rectangle/)

### challenge:

> Given an array rectangles where rectangles[i] = [xi, yi, ai, bi] represents an axis-aligned rectangle. The bottom-left point of the rectangle is (xi, yi) and the top-right point of it is (ai, bi).

> Return true if all the rectangles together form an exact cover of a rectangular region.

(for more details follow the link above)

**Note: my implementation requires at least Java 11**

### entry class Solution (given from leetcode):

```
/**
 * https://leetcode.com/problems/perfect-rectangle/
 */
public class Solution {

    //Assesment: given method within given class from leetcode - this interface may not be modified
    public boolean isRectangleCover(int[][] input) {
        InputProvider inputProvider = new InputProvider();
        inputProvider.handle(input);
        ArrayDeque<Rectangle> rectangles = inputProvider.getRectangles();
        PerfectRectangleChecker perfectRectangleChecker = new PerfectRectangleChecker(inputProvider.getBounds());
        return perfectRectangleChecker.check(rectangles);
    }
```

### class Point

```
public class Point {

    public final int x;
    public final int y;

    public Point(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Point point = (Point) o;
        return x == point.x && y == point.y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(x, y);
    }
}
```

### class Rectangle

```
public class Rectangle {

    public final Point[] points;
    public final int area;

    public Rectangle(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1) {
        points = new Point[4];
        points[0] = new Point(x0,y0);
        points[1] = new Point(x1,y0);
        points[2] = new Point(x0,y1);
        points[3] = new Point(x1,y1);
        area = (x1-x0)*(y1-y0);
    }
    public Rectangle(int[] input) {
        this(input[0],input[1],input[2],input[3]);
    }

}
```

### class InputProvider

```
public class InputProvider {

    private final ArrayDeque<Rectangle> rectangles = new ArrayDeque<>();
    private int boundsX0 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    private int boundsY0 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    private int boundsX1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    private int boundsY1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    public void handle(int[][] input) {
        Arrays.stream(input).forEach(this::processInput);
    }

    public void processInput(int[] input){
        rectangles.add(new Rectangle(input));
        updateBounds(input);
    }

    public ArrayDeque<Rectangle> getRectangles() {
        return rectangles;
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(boundsX0, boundsY0, boundsX1, boundsY1);
    }

    private void updateBounds(int[] input) {
        boundsX0 = Math.min(input[0], boundsX0);
        boundsY0 = Math.min(input[1], boundsY0);
        boundsX1 = Math.max(input[2], boundsX1);
        boundsY1 = Math.max(input[3], boundsY1);
    }

}
```

### class PerfectRectangleChecker

```
public class PerfectRectangleChecker {

    private final HashSet<Point> disjunctiveCorners = new HashSet<>();
    private final Rectangle bounds;
    private int area;

    public PerfectRectangleChecker(Rectangle bounds) {
        this.bounds = bounds;
    }

    public boolean check(ArrayDeque<Rectangle> rectangles) {
        for (Rectangle r : rectangles) {
            processRectangles(r);
        }

        if (isAreaMismatching()){
            return false;
        }

        if (boundsMismatchDisjunctivePoints()){
            return false;
        }

        if(disjunctiveCornersMismatchAmount()){
            return false;
        }

        //not simplified return statement to emphasize the three checks performed
        return true;


    }

    private boolean disjunctiveCornersMismatchAmount() {
        return disjunctiveCorners.size() != 4;
    }

    private boolean boundsMismatchDisjunctivePoints() {
        return Arrays.stream(bounds.points).anyMatch(Predicate.not(disjunctiveCorners::contains));
    }

    private boolean isAreaMismatching() {
        return area != bounds.area;
    }

    private void processRectangles(Rectangle r) {
        area = area + r.area;
        Arrays.stream(r.points).forEach(this::processDisjunctiveCorners);
    }

    private void processDisjunctiveCorners(Point p) {
        if (disjunctiveCorners.contains(p)) {
            disjunctiveCorners.remove(p);
        } else {
            disjunctiveCorners.add(p);
        }
    }
}
```

### Tests:

```
public class SolutionTest {

    final static int[][] VALID_DATA = {{1, 1, 3, 3}, {3, 1, 4, 2}, {3, 2, 4, 4}, {1, 3, 2, 4}, {2, 3, 3, 4}};
    final static int[][] INVAILD_DATA = {{0,0,1,1},{0,0,2,1},{1,0,2,1},{0,2,2,3}};

    @Test
    public void testValidInput() {
        Solution solution = new Solution();
        Assert.assertTrue( solution.isRectangleCover(VALID_DATA) );
    }

    @Test
    public void testInvalidInput() {
        Solution solution = new Solution();
        Assert.assertFalse(solution.isRectangleCover(INVAILD_DATA) );
    }

    //more test after more data is provided
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some minor changes could be applied to the code, for example the following lines :

```
ArrayDeque<Rectangle> rectangles = inputProvider.getRectangles();
public ArrayDeque<Rectangle> getRectangles() { ... }
private final HashSet<Point> disjunctiveCorners = new HashSet<>();
public boolean check(ArrayDeque<Rectangle> rectangles) { ... }
```

The could be rewritten using the [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface  and the [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) interface :

```
Deque<Rectangle> rectangles = inputProvider.getRectangles();
public Deque<Rectangle> getRectangles() { ... }
private Set<Point> disjunctiveCorners = new HashSet<>();
public boolean check(Deque<Rectangle> rectangles) { ... }
```

I see no other things I would change in your code, one reflection about the algorithm : it seems me that to see if all the rectangles together form an exact cover of a rectangular region you could add the areas of the rectangles and check if the total area is equal to the rectangle having the most sw corner and the most ne corner between all rectangles. In case of one gap between two rectangles the total area would be minor than the perfect rectangle area, in case of intersection the total area would be greater.

Following this idea I rewrote the algorithm in this way :

```
public class Solution {
    private static int calculateArea(int[] rectangle) {

        return (rectangle[2] - rectangle[0]) * (rectangle[3] -rectangle[1]); 
    }
    
    public static boolean isRectangleCover(int[][] rectangles) {
        int x0 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int y0 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int x1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int y1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        
        int totalArea = 0;
        for (int[] rectangle : rectangles) {
            x0 = Math.min(rectangle[0], x0);
            y0 = Math.min(rectangle[1], y0);
            x1 = Math.max(rectangle[2], x1);
            y1 = Math.max(rectangle[3], y1);
            totalArea += calculateArea(rectangle);
        }
     
        return totalArea == calculateArea(new int[]{x0, y0, x1, y1});
    }

}
```

I have updated the test class with cases from [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/perfect-rectangle/):

```
public class SolutionTest {
    
    //[[1,1,3,3],[3,1,4,2],[3,2,4,4],[1,3,2,4],[2,3,3,4]]
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        int[][] rectangles = {{1, 1, 3, 3}, {3, 1, 4, 2}, {3, 2, 4, 4}, {1, 3, 2, 4}, {2, 3, 3, 4}};
        assertTrue(Solution.isRectangleCover(rectangles));
    }
    
    //[[1,1,2,3],[1,3,2,4],[3,1,4,2],[3,2,4,4]]
    @Test
    public void test2() {
        int[][] rectangles = {{1, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2, 4}, {3, 1, 4, 2}, {3, 2, 4, 4}};
        assertFalse(Solution.isRectangleCover(rectangles));
    }
    
    //[[1,1,3,3],[3,1,4,2],[1,3,2,4],[3,2,4,4]]
    @Test
    public void test3() {
        int[][] rectangles = {{1, 1, 3, 3}, {3, 1, 4, 2}, {1, 3, 2, 4}, {3, 2, 4, 4}};
        assertFalse(Solution.isRectangleCover(rectangles));
    }
    
    //[[1,1,3,3],[3,1,4,2],[1,3,2,4],[2,2,4,4]]
    @Test
    public void test4() {
        int[][] rectangles = {{1, 1, 3, 3}, {3, 1, 4, 2}, {1, 3, 2, 4}, {2, 2, 4, 4}};
        assertFalse(Solution.isRectangleCover(rectangles));
    }
    
}
```

**Update :**

Thanks to Martin's comments I saw that the above solution works just for the cases available on the leetcode site without login, so the additional test cases fail. To pass all the test cases it is necessary to use the property that in a perfect rectangle the vertices are present in just one rectangle, while the others are shared by 2 or 4 rectangles.

If a vertex (x, y) is equal to a `List<Integer>` with two elements it is possible to define a custom `Comparator` that orders by x and then y like below and a specific `TreeSet`:

```
Comparator<List<Integer>> comp = (l1, l2) -> {
    int diff = l1.get(0) - l2.get(0);
            
    if (diff == 0) {
       return l1.get(1) - l2.get(1);
    }
            
    return diff;
};
SortedSet<List<Integer>> set = new TreeSet<>(comp);
int totalArea = 0;
```

Once defined it, it is possible calculate the sum of all rectangle areas and creating the set with the vertices that are owned just by one rectangle :

```
for (int[] rectangle : rectangles) {
    totalArea += calculateArea(rectangle);
    int x0 = rectangle[0];
    int y0 = rectangle[1];
    int x1 = rectangle[2];
    int y1 = rectangle[3];
    List<List<Integer>> list = List.of(List.of(x0, y0),
                                       List.of(x0, y1),
                                       List.of(x1, y0),
                                       List.of(x1, y1));
            
    for (List<Integer> pointRep : list) {
        if (set.contains(pointRep)) {
            set.remove(pointRep);
           } else {
            set.add(pointRep);
           }
    }
}
```

Because the set is ordered, if the cardinality is 4 it is possible to compare the total area with the perfect rectangle and check the result :

```
if (set.size() != 4) { return false; }
        
int[] sw = set.first().stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
int[] ne = set.last().stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
        
return totalArea ==  calculateArea(new int[] {sw[0], sw[1], ne[0], ne[1] });
```

Combining all the code lines together below my updated solution :

```
class Solution {
   public static boolean isRectangleCover(int[][] rectangles) {
        Comparator<List<Integer>> comp = (l1, l2) -> {
            int diff = l1.get(0) - l2.get(0);
            
            if (diff == 0) {
                return l1.get(1) - l2.get(1);
            }
            
            return diff;
        };
        
        SortedSet<List<Integer>> set = new TreeSet<>(comp);
        int totalArea = 0;
        
        for (int[] rectangle : rectangles) {
            totalArea += calculateArea(rectangle);
            int x0 = rectangle[0];
            int y0 = rectangle[1];
            int x1 = rectangle[2];
            int y1 = rectangle[3];
            List<List<Integer>> list = List.of(List.of(x0, y0),
                                               List.of(x0, y1),
                                               List.of(x1, y0),
                                               List.of(x1, y1));
            
            for (List<Integer> pointRep : list) {
                if (set.contains(pointRep)) {
                    set.remove(pointRep);
                } else {
                    set.add(pointRep);
                }
            }
        }
       
       if (set.size() != 4) { return false; }
        
        int[] sw = set.first().stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
        int[] ne = set.last().stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
        
        return totalArea ==  calculateArea(new int[] {sw[0], sw[1], ne[0], ne[1] });

    }
    
    private static int calculateArea(int[] rectangle) {
        
        return (rectangle[2] - rectangle[0]) * (rectangle[3] -rectangle[1]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your input - using an interface rather than an instance is a very valid input - after such long time i would go even further and provide all data (bound **and** rectangles) during constructor - thus we would inject all data on constructor (also known as **dependency injection**)

Comment: What really made me proud was when you said: *"I see no other things I would change in your code[...]"* thank you for this sentence! i though my solution was not good enough for review!!!

Comment: when i tried your code i got an failed testcase, your code returns an valid solution for the `INVALID_DATA` input - creating the proper algorithm took me really some time. That brought me to another Point of Improofment in my code: the test cases are were slim and it would be helpful to test each test-aspekt in a seperate test case! (this should i have done better)

Comment: since this review has very low attendence i'll accept your answer! please reply to my comments before i can accept!

Comment: Hello @MartinFrank, thanks for the suggestion I updated my solution with the leetcode tests I hadn't executed before without login.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your update - and for that additional explanation for the check!

Comment: @MartinFrank, you are welcome :)